# Platonic surface terminology

Tags: geometry, terminology

Just like a 2-sphere is thought of as the boundary of a 3-ball, is there an established name for the (boundary) surface of a Platonic solid?

Comment: No, not really. The 2-sphere is only used because it itself is often a useful object.

Comment: well so is the boundary of a platonic solid a useful surface ..

Comment: In what context would it be important to separate a platonic solid from its boundary?

Comment: i want to think of its boundary as a Riemann surface, in which case its faces, edges and vertices define a cochain complex

Comment: The established name for the boundary of a Platonic solid is "the boundary of a Platonic solid."